# Split one line into multiple lines while keeping the first column

Tags: awk, text-formatting

Is there any way to re-format a text file from

```
'n      n / [ ] / m / N        
'ns      @ s / @ z / @ / j @ z / j @ s        
'r      r        
's      s / z / [ ]    
...
```

to

```
'n      n 
'n      [ ] 
'n      m
'n      N        
'ns      @ s 
'ns      @ z 
'ns      @ 
'ns      j @ z 
'ns      j @ s        
'r      r        
's      s 
's      z 
's      [ ]    
...
```

That is to say, if we encounter `/`s in a line, this line would be split according to the positions of `/`s, while keeping the first column (there is always 6 spaces after first column).

I tried `tr / '\n' < filename1 > filename2` so the lines could be split like

```
'n      n 
 [ ] 
 m 
 N        
 'ns      @ s 
 @ z 
 @ 
 j @ z 
 j @ s        
 'r      r        
 's      s 
 z 
 [ ]  
...
```

but I couldn't keep the first column in the consecutive lines.

Comment: @EdMorton It's 6 blank spaces!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk in any shell on every Unix box:

If that's a tab between the first field and the rest of the line:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {n=split($2,f," */ *"); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print $1, f[i]}' file
'n      n
'n      [ ]
'n      m
'n      N
'ns     @ s
'ns     @ z
'ns     @
'ns     j @ z
'ns     j @ s
'r      r
's      s
's      z
's      [ ]
```

or if it's a series of blank chars:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/[^ ]+ +/){key=substr($0,1,RLENGTH); n=split(substr($0,1+RLENGTH),f," */ *"); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print key, f[i]}' file
'n       n
'n       [ ]
'n       m
'n       N
'ns      @ s
'ns      @ z
'ns      @
'ns      j @ z
'ns      j @ s
'r       r
's       s
's       z
's       [ ]
```

or if it's a fixed 8-chars width field at the front then you could do either:

```
$ awk '{key=substr($0,1,8); n=split(substr($0,9),f," */ *"); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print key, f[i]}' file
'n       n
'n       [ ]
'n       m
'n       N
'ns      @ s
'ns      @ z
'ns      @
'ns      j @ z
'ns      j @ s
'r       r
's       s
's       z
's       [ ]
```

or:

```
$ awk '{n=split(substr($0,9),f," */ *"); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%-8s%s\n", $1, f[i]}' file
'n      n
'n      [ ]
'n      m
'n      N
'ns     @ s
'ns     @ z
'ns     @
'ns     j @ z
'ns     j @ s
'r      r
's      s
's      z
's      [ ]
```

Comment: It's so considerate of you.... Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed  "s/ /\//" filename| awk -F "/" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $1,$i}'
```

output

```
'n      n 
'n  [ ] 
'n  m 
'n  N        
'ns      @ s 
'ns  @ z 
'ns  @ 
'ns  j @ z 
'ns  j @ s        
'r      r        
's      s 
's  z 
's  [ ]
```